# Django website stop working for some wrong time on clock issue

Tags: django

Look this Divio is cool and all but my website stop working.
I mean is it about the hosting problem or is it problem with website code or what?
it says i have wrong time on clock and browser doesn't let me visit site

what happened?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jdRC.jpg

the platform it is on is 
us.aldryn.io

from divio

i spent whole day mastering it and then this happen

Comment: You need to talk to the service provider about this issue - it's off topic here. You might also want to check that your computer does in fact not have the wrong time.

Comment: yeah not an issue anymore but some strange behaviour i was just wondering if its some maulicious activity or so

Answer (score 0):

The error in your screenshot says that your computer's clock is set incorrectly, and therefore Chrome cannot determine whether the server's certificate is still valid.

It's not related to the site.

Comment: okay thanks good to know. i was worried about it but then i also have this problem that before the site loads up i first see some sort of text code tree on the page and then in split of second site loads. i dont know what is the problem maybe also some browser issue hopefully